# ValueError at /signup/ The given username must be set

Tags: python, html, django

so basically I have been building this blogging website and now I am stuck at this point of the Signup process, the whole work is done using django

**views.py**:

```
def handleSignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # getting user parameters
        username =  request.POST.get('username')
        fname =  request.POST.get('fname')
        lname =  request.POST.get('lname')
        email =  request.POST.get('email')
        pass1 =  request.POST.get('pass1')
        pass2 =  request.POST.get('pass2')
        # fname = request.POST['fname']
        # lname = request.POST['lname']
        # email = request.POST['email']
        # pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        # pass2 = request.POST['pass2']
        

    # creating users

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username = username, email = email, password = pass1)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request, 'your account have been successfully created!')
        
        return redirect(request, 'home')

    else:
        return HttpResponse("error 404 not found")
```

**form in base.html**:

```
<form action="/signup/" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="choose a unique username">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fname">Firstname</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lname">Lastname</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email@example.com">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pass1">Choose Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass1">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pass2">Confirm password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass2">
            </div>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

          </form>
```

**now I am getting this error:**

```
ValueError at /signup/
The given username must be set
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The given username must be set
Exception Location: C:\Users\jayant nigam\projects\practise\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py, line 135, in _create_user
Python Executable:  C:\Users\jayant nigam\projects\practise\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\jayant nigam\\projects\\everythingcs',
 'C:\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\jayant nigam\\projects\\practise',
 'C:\\Users\\jayant nigam\\projects\\practise\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 28 Sep 2020 16:21:27 +0000
```

as you guys can see in **views.py** I have already tried `fname = request.POST['fname']` but then I was getting the `MultiValueDictKeyError` for which I searched on net and got a suggestion to use `request.POST.get(' ')` and after using that I am facing the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `name` to your input field in HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="choose a unique username">
</div>
```

You are not giving `name` in any of the input field. Server takes data from the form on the basis of `name`, but `not id`. So, provide name to each input tag in your form. And, you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, mate I have been stuck at this problem for the whole day and now its solved!