# value error given username must be set on django python project

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm trying register a user in my project, but when I try to do it I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The given username must be set
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']        
        password = request.POST['password']
        first_name = request.POST['fname']
        last_name = request.POST['lname']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, 
        first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.save()       
        print('user created')   
        return redirect("register")
    else:
        return render(request,'register.html')
```

Comment: Always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**. Also fix your indentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError at /signup/ The given username must be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106353/valueerror-at-signup-the-given-username-must-be-set)

Answer (score 0):

As one the guy said you should provide full error and a bit more code but from what I can guess you may need to do this:

```
        username = request.POST.get('username')
```

but again we need more ref to get what's the error.